# Request.CreateResponse versus response.Content?

Tags: c#, httpresponse

My code was

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(
                             JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data),
                             Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```

and it works fine by returning some json data.

Later I noticed that `Request.CreateResponse()` can accept a second parameter `T value` with the `value` being `the content of the HTTP response message`. So I tried to compress the above three lines into one line

```
return Request.CreateResponse(
             HttpStatusCode.OK, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data), 
             Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

But it doesn't work as expected. It returns

```
{
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "Content-Type",
      "Value": [
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Did I misunderstand the second parameter of `Request.CreateResponse()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I misunderstand the second parameter of Request.CreateResponse()

Yes, you have. The second parameter is simply the value itself. You're passing `StringContent` as `T value`, instead of letting the `CreateResponse` serialize it for you with the proper content type you pass. The reason you see no data is because `CreateResponse` probably doesn't understand how to properly serialize an object of type `StringContent`.

All you need is:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, data, "application/json"));
```